# Dynamic cube reflection mirror effect

Tags: three.js

In my project, a added a cubeCamera to the scene to get dynamic envMapping (reflection). As you see, the backside wall of the kitchen has reflection and there is some blur on it and also edges are rendered non anti-aliased. So how can i get rid of broken lines and have sharpened reflection on the wall?

Code :

```
var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(1, 1000, 256);
cubeCamera.renderTarget.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
scene.add(cubeCamera);

 var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                ambient: 0x996633,
                reflectivity: 1,
                color: 0x996633,
                specular: 0x050505,
                shininess: 100,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading, //THREE.FlatShading,
                blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                envMap: project.cubeCamera.renderTarget,
                wireframe: false
            });

objMesh.material = material;
```

in render function:

```
 objMesh.visible = false;
 objMesh.cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
 objMesh.visible = true;

 renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

So code is like every sample found on the web. No difference. But one thing i caught is, reflection on primitives is perfect, but reflection on custom mesh loaded from obj file is poor.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Without seeing code, who knows? But I would do it differently. Make the "mirror" partially transparent, and add a room on the other side that is the reverse of this room. The "reflection" will be perfect -- except the camera won't see it's own reflection, which is a good thing. :-)

Comment: Another room cannot be added because this project is highly interactive for the end user. Can add new furniture, create new scene etc... I updated question with code snippet. The main problem is, if I add sphere in the scene and set envMap as the same cube camera's renderTarget, (with updating the position of course) sphere reflects the scene perfectly. But same thing does not happen if reflective geometry is a custom object loaded from obj file...

Comment: Another issue which may be a bug. Reflection on spherical objects is perfect, while moving the camera away the scene, reflected texture scales as it should be. But when we add reflection to flat surfaced geometries like cube, reflection scale is always constant. I mean when we move camera away from scene, the reflection texture is not scaling.

Comment: Resolution was the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment mapping is based on the assumption that the environment is infinitely far away, which is not a valid approximation in your case. Therefore, you will see artifacts you don't like.

The broken edge effect may be reduced if you double the resolution of your cube camera.